# How to check if somebody wrote a review to my Android App

Tags: android, google-play, vote

In my Android App i want a popup do show up with a button that links to my app in the market.
The popup is showing currectly, but if somebody has already wrote a review for my app, i dont want it to show up.
Is it possible to check if the person has already wrote a review or gave stars?

Sorry for my bad english. I hope you did understand my problem.^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really. You can have your app remember that the specific user has pressed your pop-up button before to be taken to the market. But you have no way to know whether they rated or reviewed your application. The Market provides no public API to get this information for 3rd party applications.

Comment: I already thought about your solution, but if they press the button, its not a garantee they actully rated. I need to be sure they rated or reviewed.

Comment: Two years have passed and there still seem to be no way of checking whether the user rated the app. user1374864's say's right, this is a problem. Why would I bother the user rating the app if they rated it already by going directly to the market? However, if the app has a Rate app! button or a dialog that comes up sometimes, I think the user will extremely rarely go the market to rate it instead of clicking on your button in the application.