# How can I check whether the current account has reviewed my Android application in Google Play?

Tags: android

Currently in my Android application I have a popup that brings the user to my application in the Google Play store so they can review my application. I would like to display the popup only if the current user account has not reviewed my application yet. Is it possible to check if the account has already written a review or rated the application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you to check if a user has rated your app on the android market?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284549/how-do-you-to-check-if-a-user-has-rated-your-app-on-the-android-market), [How to check if somebody wrote a review to my Android App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537971/how-to-check-if-somebody-wrote-a-review-to-my-android-app) and [How to know if a specific user has rated a Android App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318700/how-to-know-if-a-specific-user-has-rated-a-android-app)

Comment: Create your own script... or ask a new stackoverflow question "How to create script that checks if somebody wrote a review to my Android Application?" :)

Comment: I want to open additional content after the evaluation.

Comment: The only solutions to do that seems to be in violation of *Google* policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no official Google API to access *Google Play* data, however, there is an unofficial
[`android-market-api`](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) that may allow you to list all your app's comments.

Example from [android-market-api wiki](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowToGetAppComments) :

```
CommentsRequest commentsRequest = CommentsRequest.newBuilder()
                                .setAppId("7065399193137006744")
                                .setStartIndex(0)
                                .setEntriesCount(10)
                                .build();

 session.append(commentsRequest, new Callback<CommentsResponse>() {
  @Override
    public void onResult(ResponseContext context, CommentsResponse response) {
        System.out.println("Response : " + response);
        // response.getComments(0).getAuthorName()
        // response.getComments(0).getCreationTime()
        // ...
    }
});

session.flush();
```

Which is suppose to output something like :

```
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "rating": 5,
      "creationTime": 1269710736815,
      "authorName": "Nate Kidwell",
      "text": "Tremendous application. More examples would be great (as would integrated rubydocs), but awesome all the same.",
      "authorId": "04441815096871118032"
    },
...
```

You may then be able to identify the current user in the comment list to check if he already reviewed your app or not.

Comment: I need only the fact of a comment rather than texts.

Comment: @user2413972 This API is only crawling Google Play in order to get the list of an application review. (A thing you can do yourself by sending HTTP request to `play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.yourapp`). You would then need the User name or ID to check whether he posted a review.